# Send an event(Object) from server to a specific client

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to send Server event to a specific user. Also I want to send an object instead of a string and finding it difficult to achieve this.

In the onlineUsers variable, I'm storing all the users active now. Then finding this user to send an object.

```
Let onlineUsers=[]
let Data =[]

function sendEventtoOne(request){
  const targetUser = onlineUsers.filter((user)=> user.userId === request.userId);
  targetUser.response.write(`data: ${request})`) 
}

  async function addFact(request, respsonse, next) {
    Data.push(request);
    response.json(request)
    return sendEventtoOne(request);
  }
```

Quite new to programming. Would appreciate your help to send an object to client.

Comment: Send the object as string `JSON.stringify(object)` and then In your client decode that string with `JSON.parse(response)` .

Comment: Thanks for your response. Would I need \n\n (object )in this case?

Comment: It is an object it will be ok.